# return deleted node after DETACH DELETE

Tags: neo4j

I have a problem to get node record in result after I deleted the node.

My query is:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(comment:Comment)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(post:Post)
WHERE comment.uuid = {commentUUID} AND post.uuid = {postUUID} AND user.uuid = {userUUID} AND NOT EXISTS(user.deleted)
DETACH DELETE comment
RETURN comment
```

Here I am deleting comment which belongs to some post (BELONGS_TO). I also check if user who wants to delete the comment is also author of this comment (CREATED).

Query works, the deletion of node and relationship happen successfully, but I am not satisfied with returned value.

It shows me this result instead:

```
{ metadata: { deleted: true, id: 89 },
  paged_traverse: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}',
  outgoing_relationships: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/relationships/out',
  outgoing_typed_relationships: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}',
  labels: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/labels',
  create_relationship: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/relationships',
  traverse: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/traverse/{returnType}',
  all_relationships: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/relationships/all',
  all_typed_relationships: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}',
  property: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/properties/{key}',
  self: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89',
  incoming_relationships: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/relationships/in',
  properties: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/properties',
  incoming_typed_relationships: 'http://myDatabaseURI/db/data/node/89/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}' }
```

Thanks for help!

Edit:

I hide my db URI in result and replaced it with myDatabaseURI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, when you delete a node, you cannot return its properties by returning the node itself.

However, you can get the properties of the node before the deletion, and return that after deleting the node itself:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(comment:Comment)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(post:Post)
WHERE comment.uuid = {commentUUID} AND post.uuid = {postUUID} AND user.uuid = {userUUID} AND NOT EXISTS(user.deleted)
WITH comment, properties(comment) as props
DETACH DELETE comment
RETURN props
```

This won't get you the node id, though, so if you need to return that, you can use map projection to get all properties plus the node id instead.

Comment: Thanks, will do get comment query before deleting it.